# Split a list into sublists in java using if possible flatMap

Tags: java, list, split, functional-programming, java-stream

here is my list:

```
List<Integer> mylist = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
```

Assuming my list is always even, then i would like to split it in 6 equal parts.

List as a Sketch:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Output Sketch:

```
[[1,2][3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
```

I would prefer a solution if possible with Java 8 stream `flatMap`

Comment: `Stream`-operations, by their nature, [should be stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). The task to perform inherently needs state. Those two ideas conflict. I suggest to not use `Stream`s to perform this task.

Comment: `flatMap` takes away splits; it doesn't put them in.  But more to the point, streams can't do this.

Comment: What should i use then?

Comment: There are plenty possibilities. The first coming to my mind would be to use a regular `for`-loop.

Comment: is there a way to do it with functional programming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the "sublists" are all of equal size and that you can divide the list into exact sublists of the same size, you could calculate the desired size and then map an `IntStream` to the starting indexes of each sublist and use that to extract them:

```java
List<Integer> mylist = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
int size = mylist.size();
int parts = 6;
int partSize = size / parts;
List<List<Integer>> result = 
    IntStream.range(0, parts)
             .mapToObj(i -> mylist.subList(i * partSize, (i + 1) * partSize)))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:**
[IdeOne demo](https://ideone.com/dGQ5Rs) graciously provided by @Turing85

Comment: @Turing85 got caught up in my own head, and forgot to multiply by the `partSize`. Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: One right parenthesis at the mapToObj line should be deleted : )

Answer (score 2):

I know it out of the scope but another possibility is using a library like **Guava** which has a lot of methods related to List.

**Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

**Example**

```
package com.stackoverflow.question;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> mylist = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
        List<List<Integer>> partionList = Lists.partition(mylist, 2);
        
        System.out.println(partionList);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Stream`-operations should be stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). The task to perform inherently needs state. Thus, I would recommend not using `Stream`. Instead, I would recommend a `for`-loop based solution:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> partition(
        List<Integer> list, 
        int partitionSize) {
    final int listSize = list.size();
    if (listSize % partitionSize != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size of the list must be "
                + "divisible without remainder by the partition size.");
    }
    
    final List<List<Integer>> partition = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int start = 0; start < listSize; start += partitionSize) {
        partition.add(list.subList(start, start + partitionSize));
    }
    return partition;
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/tUrtLE)

If we insist on using a `Stream`-based implementation, I would suggest using the code presented [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525086/4216641).

Answer (score 1):

The following will work for any group size from 1 to the `size of the list`. If the group size does not evenly divided the list size then the remainder will be put into their own group.

Also, the extra `map(ArrayList::new)` ensures the sublist is put in its own list.  Otherwise, changing the original list entries will also change the sublist entries.

```
int gsize = 2;
List<Integer> mylist =
        Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
    List<List<Integer>> subLists = IntStream
            .iterate(0, i -> i < mylist.size(),
                    i -> i + gsize)
            .mapToObj(i -> mylist.subList(i,
                    (i + gsize <= mylist.size()) ?
                            i + gsize : mylist.size()))
            .map(ArrayList::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
System.out.println(subLists);
```

Prints

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

If the group size was 5, the new list would look like the following:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want a solution with flatMap, you can try something like this, not an intuitive solution though. At the end it only need to return a Stream, so this is simply constructing sub lists as it progress and returning it as Stream at the end.

btw, I personally prefer Guava's `Lists.partition`

```
List result = list.stream().flatMap(new Function<>() {

                 List<List<Integer>> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
                 List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<>(2);
                 int index = 0;

                 @Override
                 public Stream<?> apply(Integer integer) {
                     subList.add(integer);

                     if ((index + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                         mainList.add(subList);
                         subList = new ArrayList<>(2);
                     }
                     index++;
                     if (index == list.size()) {
                         if(!subList.isEmpty()) {
                             mainList.add(subList);
                         }
                         return mainList.stream();
                     }
                     return Stream.empty();
                 }

             }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```